# SSRS Interface changed overnight

Tags: reporting-services

When I came in to work yesterday, I went to run my usual reports. I go to 192.168.1.43/Reports like usual and was greeted with this error. [image]

First I noticed the IP address changed, easy enough. I go to 192.168.1.44/Reports. But I was greeted with the same error (since then I changed this server to a static IP). The only thing that works is if I go to 192.168.1.44/ReportServer. Then the interface looks like this. My subscriptions are still running but I can not get to them. I've been trying to figure this out for more than a full day at this point. Any help would be very much appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The view you can see in your screenshot is normal, this is the Web Service URL.

The bit that is not working is the Web Portal URL which, by default, is the same address but ending in `/Reports` as you have already tried.

This may not resolve the problem but the first thing to check is that the address is configured correctly.

Open "Reporting Services Configuration Manager", connect you your report server when prompted (just the server name or address is required)

Then check the "Web Portal URL" tab

(this is based on SQL Server 2016 so may be slightly different on your version)

[image]

If the address is incorrect, click "Advanced" to make changes

Comment: Yeah I tried this. Funny enough, now the /Reports URL seems to be working but I'm still getting the web service URL view. At least now I know what I am looking for is the web PORTAL URL, so thank you for that. Another step closer.